# 50 People All over the World hit web app versus 50 people on the Same LAN? Any difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, passenger

At my office we use a LAN (connected to internet through Comcast) and 30-50 people all accessed a web app (on Heroku) simultaneously. The server responded as if it had been hit by 50K people. Am I barking up the wrong tree, or would it make a difference if 50 people on an office network hit an app at the same time versus 50 people spread across the globe?

Apologies for such a vague question, but it only just occurred to me as a possibility.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "server responded as if it had been hit by 50K people"?

Comment: Meaning even the simplest read/write operations timed out. Since it's Heroku I thought maybe it was due to request being routed to idle Dynos that needed to spin up, but according to Heroku, that is only the case if your app utilizes only a single Dyno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having 50 people access your app simultaneously will have roughly the same effect, no matter where they come from. There is no more effort required to serve local requests than global requests (or vice versa). If your app has a performance problem, then consider yourself lucky that you've exposed it before turning on public access!

Comment: Having 50 people on a LAN *exactly* at the same time would likely slightly the impact response time as they would be typically be queued and answered more or less sequentially where as responses over the internet at large would have more varying latencies and hence the time to respond per request would likely be slightly lower. Unless (a) your HTTP server has VERY little free memory to queue these requests or (b) your router is being overloaded, I highly suspect the performance hit you're seeing is your code's fault. :)